# Why is the `puts` function called puts?

Tags: c

I can find the function `puts` on most of all programming languages such C, Ruby, Python, etc and started to wonder why it is named `puts`.

I have tried to google with any possible key words but in vain.

Is there a history of the naming of `puts`?

I am pretty sure that `s` stands for string but "put string" doesn't make sense to me compared to `print string`.

Please let me know the right place to ask if this question doesn't belong to here, thank you!

Comment: [This description](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_puts.htm) may help.  It is short for _put string_.

Comment: Similarly `putc` and `getc` and (now obsolete) `gets`.

Comment: There is a family of `fprintf` and `fscanf` related functions for formatted I/O, and another family of `fput` and `fget` related functions which do not use formatting. I suspect that `prints` or `fprints` would be confusing names (and there is already an `sprintf`), and `print_string` might just be too verbose for the Standard Library.

Comment: @adabsurdum a lot of old linkers and compilers could only handle short names (~6 characters for example). So early C names were made short to handle this. And later C names were made to follow existing C naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to recall C's origins as a very terse language. Thus, `puts` — the idea being that the parametric string is indeed being "put" somewhere (or "out**put**," if that makes the convention a little clearer) — is quicker to type than `print`. Most of the languages that still use that function name for that feature are either built on C or were trying to cater to C coders.

Also, when C was first conceived, I suspect "printing" was very much reserved for the idea of a tractor-feed dot-matrix printer.

Comment: Also worth noting that many old languages had actual limits on the length of identifiers, 6 being common. So all the terse names we see in C are not just for fun. `print` is 5 letters already, and there's already a lot of `print` functions in C. Do we really want to have to distinguish them all by a single letter suffix?